# url not redirecting correctly to canonical

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My website uses .htaccess redirect as below:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The issue is that

> Warning, no 301 redirects are in place to redirect traffic to your preferred domain. Pages that load successfully both with and without www. are treated as duplicate content!
> Not all versions of your page point to the same URL.
>
> URL Resolved URL:
>
> 1. `http://example.com/inner-page` redirects to `https://example.com/inner-page`
> 2. `http://www.example.com/inner-page` redirects to
>    `https://example.com/index.php/inner-page`
> 3. `https://example.com/inner-page` redirects to
>    `https://example.com/inner-page`
> 4. `https://www.example.com/inner-page` redirects to
>    `https://example.com/index.php/inner-page`

Why the same URL is behaving differently with browser. What should I change in the `.htaccess` file so that it can redirect to the proper URL? I'm wondering how this strange behaviour can happen?

What is the solution so that they all redirect to only

```
https://example.com/inner-page
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Your rules are in the wrong order. You are redirecting to HTTP, not HTTPS. You are not specifically redirecting HTTP to HTTPS.

---

> 1. `http://example.com/inner-page` redirects to `https://example.com/inner-page`

This redirect is not performed by the `.htaccess` directives you've posted. This is probably triggered by your PHP/application.

Your rule in `.htaccess` only redirects `www.example.com`, not `example.com`.

> 2. `http://www.example.com/inner-page` redirects to `https://example.com/index.php/inner-page`

Because your rules are in the wrong order. The first rule rewrites the request to `/index.php/inner-page` first and it's this URL that is then being redirected. But this is actually 2 redirects, since the directives you've posted redirect to HTTP, not HTTPS.

Your 2nd rule will trigger a redirect to `http://example.com/index.php/inner-page` (note HTTP) and your PHP/application is probably redirecting this to HTTPS (see above).

> 3. `https://example.com/inner-page` redirects to `https://example.com/inner-page`

That's not a redirect. Nothing is happening in this scenario. (Which is correct.)

> 4. `https://www.example.com/inner-page` redirects to
>    `https://example.com/index.php/inner-page`

Same as #2 above. (Except you are redirecting the request back to HTTP first and you are relying on PHP/application redirecting back to HTTPS - see above.)

Your current rules do not specifically redirect HTTP to HTTPS, they only redirect www to non-www. And this *should* redirect to HTTPS, not HTTP.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect www to non-www (+ HTTPS)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(example\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Front-controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

The HTTP to HTTPS redirect assume the SSL cert is managed by your application server, ie. you are not using a CDN, load balancer, front-end caching proxy etc. (Otherwise this might trigger a redirect loop.)

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: after doing as suggested this is what happens, pls suggest edits http://example.com/inner-page  https://example.com/inner-page
http://www.example.com/inner-page  ENOTFOUND
https://example.com/inner-page  https://example.com/inner-page
https://www.example.com/inner-page ENOTFOUND

Comment: @AjayJain I'm not sure what you mean (some information is missing). Use backticks for inline code/URLs to preserve formatting. Make sure you are using 302 (temporary) redirects and ensure you are testing with the browser cache disabled (ie. with browser devtools open and "disable cache" checked.)

Comment: sir i change htacess file as directed by u, both http and https the urls with www are showing ENOTFOUND

Comment: @AjayJain Btw, you still need the `RewriteEngine On` directive at the top. (The directives won't do anything without that and you'll just get 404s.) I've updated my answer to clarify that.

Comment: RewriteEngine On is there sir,

the redirect on http without www and https non www are working fine whereas the http with www and https with www are not

Comment: @AjayJain That doesn't seem to make much sense. What actually happens when you request the www subdomain? Are you redirected?